# Are Euclid's Axioms Non-Logical or Logical?

Tags: logic, meta-math

This question may seem trivial, but I recently became aware of the distinction between the two types of axioms: logical and non-logical.

> What category does Euclid's fall under?

I would assume they would be non-logical, since his axioms are not universal truths (i.e. tautologies) as we know them.

Comment: You are right; they are not "universally valid" and thus they are not logical axioms.

Answer (score 3):

A logical axiom, must be stated ONLY in terms of logical concepts, for example logical connectives and logical quantifiers. As you know, Euclid's axioms are about geometrical concepts; not only they contain logical quantifiers, but also they contain statements about points, lines and so on.
It's because of this fact, that you can change Euclid's axioms and have non-Euclidean geometries.